# Ubuntu 16.4 - No signal on vga after lock screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm running on ubuntu 16.4.
My problem occured this morning at work, until now I have not had this issue. I have not installed any drivers to my knowledge.

When I boot ubuntu, my second monitor is detected and the Ubuntu lock/login screen displays. When I login and start my session, the second monitor looses signal and Ubuntu doesn't seem to find it when I "detect displays" on the display tab of the setting menu.

How can I fix this?

thanks,